# Selecting data between the fixed date every month in SQL dynamically

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I was using the below sql query to pull report for the last month.

```
Select * from TABLE
where datediff(month, InvoiceDate, Getdate()) = 1
```

I link this SQL query to Excel Power Query to generate the monthly report automatically by just 1 refresh click.

Now my issue is that our reporting has changed from 26th of last month to 25th of the current month, so the above SQL query will not give me the correct report. Plus I have to add the date every month to generate the report.

Is there a way to add the date in where clause dynamically to generate the report every month, so that my tool work the way it was working earlier

Comment: if you refresh the report today, what interval data will be displayed? Similarly, if you refresh at 26th of this month, which range of data to be displayed?

Comment: If I refresh the report today it will displayed the data for last month, i.e from 1st of the last month till last date of the last month. Even if I refresh it on 26th.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a table and inserted values into that table.

Image for reference:

[image]

I fetched inserted values where invocedate is between 2022-09-01 and 2022-09-30 using below code.

```
declare @Startdate date=dateadd(MM, -1,getdate())
    
declare @Enddate date=dateadd(MM, -1,getdate())

declare @startingdate date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@Startdate)-1),@Startdate))

declare @endingdate date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,@Enddate))),
DATEADD(mm,1,@Enddate)))

select * from report where invocedate between @startingdate AND @endingdate
```

Image for reference:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, after making few changes I am able to get the desire result, actually I needed the date between 26th of last month to 25th of current month. Below are the changes I have made, hope this will work well for me. Thanks again

declare '@Startdate date=dateadd(MM, -1,getdate())
declare '@Enddate date=dateadd(MM, -1, getdate())

declare '@startingdate date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@Startdate)-25),@Startdate))
declare '@endingdate date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,@Enddate))-26),
DATEADD(mm,1,@Enddate)))